# Can I optimize a left join for a single match?

Tags: sql-server, join

Consider a join `A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.a_id`:

- `B.a_id` is nullable -- most but not all `B` records point to an `A` record.
- `A` can, *at most*, only have *one* matching `B` record (business logic).
- Not all `A` records have a match in `B`.

Is there a way to tell MSSQL that there will *never* be *more than* one A:B match, thus allowing it to shortcut the join once a match is found for a given `A` record?

I would think that such an optimization could happen if `B.a_id` had a unique index, but that's not possible since it's nullable.

Complicating the issue: A and B are in different databases (same MSSQL instance).

If it matters, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*<sub>Wiki answer from a comment on the question by [@ypercube](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube):</sub>*

---

You can use a filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX a_id_uq 
ON b (a_id) 
WHERE a_is IS NOT NULL;
```

See [Filtered Index Design Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372(v=sql.105).aspx)